# Access Model object in a JSP without using the ModelAndView object?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc with Annotations, see the following snippet

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/configuration/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public MyModel viewConfiguration() {
```

The problem I am having accessing the 'MyModel' class in my JSP.

How can I do this, without using the ModelAndView object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shorthand syntax means that `MyModel` becomes a model attribute named `myModel` (i.e. class name with the first letter decapitalized).

View name is inferred from the URL.

**See also:**

- [15.3.2.3 Supported handler method arguments and return types](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-arguments)
- [15.10.3 The View - RequestToViewNameTranslator](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-arguments)

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem, sometimes the solution is just to easy!

Answer (score 0):

You could set `MyModel` as a request attribute to be accessed in your JSP. I'm curious, why don't you want to use `ModelAndView`? After all, it does what you want to do here, which displays the view and provides a container to hold your objects you want to reference in your view.

By the way, if this is an Ajax call, you will need to add `@ResponseBody` to the API so that your javascript can read the response in the callback function:-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/configuration/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody MyModel viewConfiguration() {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I have several view resolvers (JSP,JSON,XML) on top of my controller, for JSON I use a library with API classes to serialize and deserialize my JSON objects between server and client applications, because of JSON it is favourable to keep my controllers as is. I am mostly curious if this is possible in my current setup.